# Django trigram_similar search returns no result (Django 2.1 with Postgresql 10.5 backend)

Tags: django, postgresql, trigram

I followed the instruction on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#std:fieldlookup-trigram_similar to install trigram search on my search engine. I added `'django.contrib.postgres'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and installed the `pg_trgm` extension on my PostgreSQL database. The trigram search returns no result, but there is no error, just blankness where there should be search results. My search engine worked fine with `icontain` searches. Here is the code for my search engine with `trigram_similar`:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.filter(Title__trigram_similar=search_term)
```

`Title` is a `CharField` in my model `cross_currents`:

```
class cross_currents(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

This is what my Django shell gave me:

```
In [6]: cross_currents.objects.filter(Title__trigram_similar='modern')
Out[6]: <QuerySet []>
```

The HTML page also returns nothing. However, when I do

```
cross_currents.objects.filter(Title__icontains='modern')
```

many results show up. Any idea why my trigram search returns nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the default similarity threshold of Postgres is set to 0.3, which is way too high to return results for single word searches in my case. I find a threshold of 0.01 to be effective in my case:

```
articles = articles.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term),).filter(similarity__gt=0.01).order_by('-similarity')
```

Comment: I think 0.01 is way too low and it is picking up almost everything in the search results. Shouldn't it be 0.1?